# How do I resample a raster layer over another layer in QGIS 3.x?

Tags: qgis, resampling

I have 2 raster layers (the full same area):

Layer 1: 30 m resolution, coordinate system is EPSG:32643, layer size is 7406x6801;
Layer 2: 10 m resolution, coordinate system is WGS 84, layer size is 56466x21902.

I want to resample layer 2 like layer 1 (i.e., make a resolution of 30 m and the coordinate system EPSG:32643). To do this, I used the Raster -> Projections -> Warp tool, where I specified a resolution of 30 m and the desired coordinate system. However, the size of the output layer became 7580x6921 instead of 7406x6801, plus a pixel offset appeared.

I cannot specify a reference layer in the Warp settings, and another tool (Align Rasters), where this can be allowed, immediately throws an error when executed.

How do I get a new layer based on layer 2 so that the size is like layer 1?

Comment: You should be able to use the -te <xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax> (get these values from your existing raster) switch in the warp options, that should force it to match your existing raster. You shouldn't need to specify -te_srs EPSG:32643 to ensure your units are recognized as metres as the default is in the target CRS https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te.